# how to find the factor of $x^{12}$in $(1-4x)^{-5}$

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

> Find the factor of $x^{12}$ in $(1-4x)^{-5}$

Any hints how can i find that?

Comment: Why do you need it? And have you heard of the negative binomial series?

Comment: Do you mean the coefficient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the binomial series we have,

$$(1+(-4x))^{-5}=\sum_{k \geq 0} {-5 \choose k} (-4x)^k$$

---

Hence,

> $$[x^{12}] (1-4x)^{-5}={-5 \choose 12} (-4)^{12}=\frac{-5(-6)(-7)...(-16)}{12!} (-4)^{12}=\frac{4^{12}}{12!}\prod_{k=5}^{16} k$$

Answer (score 3):

By the generalized binomial theorem
(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Generalizations),
$(1-x)^{-s}
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{s+k-1}{s-1}x^k
$.

In your case,
$s=5$
so that
$(1-4x)^{-5}
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{k+4}{4}(4x)^k
$.

The coefficient of $x^{12}$ is
$\binom{12+4}{4}(4)^{12}
=\binom{16}{4}(4)^{12}
=\dfrac{2^{24}16\ 15\ 14\ 13}{4\ 3\ 2}
=2^{24}2\ 5\ 14\ 13
$.